# Extracting text from a PDF file in Python

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to extract text from a pdf file I usually have to deal with at work, so that I can automize it.

When using PyPDF2, it works for my CV for instance, but not for my work-document. The problem is, that the text is then like that: "Helloworldthisisthetext". I then tried to use .join(" "), but this is not working.

I read that this is a known problem with PyPDF2 - it seems to depend on the way the pdf was built.

Does anyone know another approach how to extract text out of it which I then can use for further steps?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please consider adding some more details to help others help you. How is the pdf generated? Do you get any error messages? How is your own CV generated? Et cetera...

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to try another tool - [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/). You can extract the both plain strings and "PDF markdown" (decoded text strings + operators). "PDF markdown" can be parsed as a regular text (with regular expressions for example).

Below you find the code sample for walking pages and extracting PDF content for further parsing.

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(your_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown = viewer.canvas.text_content
        result = my_text_parser(pdf_markdown)
        # The one below will probably be the same as PyPDF2 returns        
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass

...

def my_text_parser(text):
    """ Code your parser here """
    ...
```

*pdf_markdown* variable contains all texts including PDF commands (positioning, display): all strings come in brackets followed by *Tj* or *TJ* operator.
For more on PDF text operators see [PDF 1.7 sec. 9.4 Text Objects](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=248)

You can parse it with regular expressions for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement at work for which I used [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). They also have a collection of recipes which cover typical scenarios of text extraction.